# Generating manual install guide from ansible

Tags: ansible

We have ansible playbooks to automate our deployment. I've got a client that wants to do everything himself (without using ansible) and asks us for an install procedure.

Is there a way to output the steps that ansible would run, to generate an install guide?

Answer (score 1):

Short version: no, unless your playbook is entirely `raw:`, `command:`, or `shell:` tasks, in which case "possibly"

Medium version: perhaps with `ansible-playbook -vvvv --check`

Long version: tell them to actually *read* the playbook; unlike some other systems, with ansible being described entirely by yaml files, I think it is very straightforward to look at a playbook and tell what is going to happen. Or, [fire your customer](https://blog.freelancersunion.org/2015/02/12/how-fire-your-client/) because that's just a silly request.

Comment: I like the "fire your customer" option!